# How to define a max function for every type with a method ">"?

Tags: scala, comparison, language-design, max

Is it possible to define it generically over all types which have a method `>` (also all AnyVals) so that using a single implementation method is enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you declare an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def greater2order[A](self : { def >(that : A) }) : Order[A] = ...
```

and then just use scalaz...

Comment: You mean `implicit def`? I have been trying this route, I run quickly into *Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to a type member of that refinement* type of error.

Comment: That was my problem, too. Something like `Numeric[T]` worked, though.

Answer (score 3):

The standard library sort of does it already. But without assigning a type to the object having the `>` method...

```
List(1,2,3).max(Ordering.fromLessThan( (a:Int, b:Int) => b > a) )
```

Basically this syntax will work for anything that has a `>` method or where some implicit conversion makes `>` available. It creates an Ordering that can be passed to the standard `max` method.

One more example:

```
case class S(s:String) {
  def >(that:S) = java.text.Collator.getInstance.compare(s, that.s) > 0
}

List(S("abc"), S("ABa"), S("abd")).max(Ordering.fromLessThan( (a:S,b:S) => b>a) )
// res9: S = S(abd)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Ordering trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html) may be relevant.

It covers the standard numerical types (and then some -- see "Known Subclasses"). Implicits can be used to "open it up" across external types.

Happy coding.